# Telling Scully to Ignore Static Page Generation for a Route?

Tags: angular, typescript, seo, angular-ivy, scullyio

Suppose we have the following routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WelcomeComponent
  },  
  {
    path: 'start',
    component: StartComponent
  }
```

Is the a way to tell Scully to skip generation fo a static page for the `start` route?

Comment: I’m sure this is possible.. don’t exactly know how, but I recommend asking this question in the scully gitter: https://gitter.im/scullyio/community

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the `ignoredRoutePlugin`.

```
`/someRoute`:{
  type:'ignored'
}
```

It doesn't look like it's in the documentation yet but here is the code in the repo: https://github.com/scullyio/scully/blob/main/libs/scully/src/lib/routerPlugins/ignoredRoutePlugin.ts

Comment: Can I somehow use wildcard? Eg.: `/someRoute/*`
Have tried * but without results.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a "wilcard"-ignore, you can use a `routeProcessPlugin`, declared in `./scully/plugins/plugin.ts`:

```
import { HandledRoute, registerPlugin } from '@scullyio/scully';

registerPlugin(
  'routeProcess',
  'filteredRoute',
  (routes: HandledRoute[]): Promise<HandledRoute[]> => {
    return Promise.resolve(routes.filter((r) => !r.route.startsWith('/someRoute')));
  },
);
```

Make sure to import it in your `scully.config.ts`:

```
import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';
require('./scully/plugins/plugin');

export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  // your config here
}
```

Comment: this works super useful. thank you